# jQuery 1.6.2 Replace Text Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of jQuery I have been using to set default text in a search box, remove the text when the user enters the search box, and then adds the text again if the search box loses focus. The code is as follows:

```
//global vars
var searchBox = jQuery("#plc_lt_mpHeaderContent_SiteSearch_txtWord");
var searchBoxDefaultText = "Keyword, Title, Name";

searchBox.val('Keyword, Title, Name');

//searchbox show/hide default text if needed
searchBox.focus(function () 
{

    if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == searchBoxDefaultText) jQuery(this).attr("value", "");

});

searchBox.blur(function () 
{

    if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "") jQuery(this).attr("value", searchBoxDefaultText);

});
```

This code is launched in the jQuery(document).ready(function ()). The issue is that this works as expected in jQuery 1.4.2, but when I try the same code in jQuery 1.6.2 it does not work. I am wondering what I need to do to get it to be compliant with 1.6.2. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What "doesn't work"?  Are the event handlers not called?  Does the comparison not evaluate to true?  Is the value not set?

Comment: The removal/addition of text on focus and blur was the problem, sorry for not properly stating that. I will give val a try. I'm sure that will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery 1.6 update changed how attr works. Now you have to use prop instead. Release notes here http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

Even better would be to use .val(), like this:

```
searchBox.focus(function () 
{

    if (jQuery(this).val() == searchBoxDefaultText) jQuery(this).val("");

});

searchBox.blur(function () 
{

    if (jQuery(this).val() == "") jQuery(this).val(searchBoxDefaultText);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

change the .attr() to .val()

```
searchBox.focus(function () 
{
 if ($(this).val() == searchBoxDefaultText)
 {
  $(this).val();
 }
});

searchBox.blur(function () 
{
 if ($(this).val()=="")
  {
   $(this).val(searchBoxDefaultText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you say `jQuery(this).val("")` instead of `jQuery(this).attr("value", "")` -- whether that's your problem, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *jQuery(this).attr("value")*, I would use:

```
jQuery(this).val();                        // for getting value
jQuery(this).val(searchBoxDefaultText);    // for setting value
```

That said, I'll also recommend you look into HTML5's *placeholder* attribute (for compatible browsers), and then adding jQuery.hint (or any of the many similar plugins) for non-HTML5 browsers. Don't reinvent the wheel.